# Schema Markup : Using Service and Webpage Types on the Same Page

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I have taken over the general administration of a business website. On the service pages, two separate instances of structured data are being loaded (the `Service` schema type, and the `Webpage` schema type).

```js
<script type='application/ld+json'>
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@type": "Service",
        "serviceType": "Service Type Here",
        "alternateName": "Alternate Service Name Here",
        "description": "Description Here",
        "mainEntityOfPage": "https://www.WebsiteAddress.com/service-type",
        "name": "Service Name"
    } 
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "name": "Webpage Name",
        "url": "https://www.WebsiteAddress.com/service-type",
        "inLanguage":"en-US",
        "description": "Description Here",
        "publisher": {
        "name": "Business Name"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Could the current setup cause conflicts with how search engines interpret the page?

As most of the tags are duplicates, would it make more sense to remove the Webpage type schema markup and add the `brand` tag into the Service schema?

Interested to hear opinions on this.

Comment: Ask yourself: what is the main idea? Then, what assets support the main idea? In this case, the main idea is the WebPage. This particular WebPage isPartOf a WebSite. The WebPage presents information about ... (a Service). so take this approach and do your mark-up.

Answer (score 2):

**About your Q**. The short answer is **YES** => It's ok to declare two types (-or- more) on the same page (No "one rule" her - it's related to page structure/content).

**"duplication" -**
First `As most of the tags are duplicates` is a wrong sentence (One time the name related to `webPage` object and one time for `service` object). If in your specific case "service name" = "page name" it's ok to use the same value (This is the true semantic meaning of your content).

### WebPage & Service

`WebPage` is a special type:

> **Every** web page is implicitly assumed to be declared to be of type
> WebPage. https://schema.org/WebPage

If you look at this issue in the **microdata** approach it's easier to understand the structure/idea of the sentence above.

a.**The webpage** (Again - Every page assumed to be of type WebPage):

```
<body itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Our services</h1>
</body>
```

b.**The service**

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TaxiService">
    <h2 itemprop="name">Drive to airport</h2>
</div>
```

a & b - could look like this:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Our services</h1>
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TaxiService">
    <h2 itemprop="name">Drive to airport</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

If page name = service name - you could do something like this:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Drive to airport">
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TaxiService">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Drive to airport</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Nothing wrong her**.

1/2. The page name is "Drive to airport" (true):
[image]

2/2. And the service name is "Drive to airport" (true):
[image]

If the service is the [main entity](https://schema.org/mainEntity) of [webPage](https://schema.org/WebPage) this outline is a good start point (Close to your Q code example):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "name": "Our services",
  "breadcrumb": "main > Our services",
  "mainEntity":{
          "@type": "service",
          "name": "Drive to airport"
        }
}
</script>
```

[image]